# read_excel truncates numbers in spite of setting digits option

Tags: r, xlsx, data-import, readxl

I am trying to read an excel file into R with `read_excel()` function from the "readxl" package.
Numbers in cells in the excel file have 3 decimal places, e.g. 
`0,684 1,338 74,296`. In the R dataframe the same numbers are `0,684 1,34 74,3`.
Why did only 3 digits remain?

I have set `options(digits=5)` (tried different values as well) .

I have also tried to `read_excel("file.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text", "text"))` (which gave me strings: `74.296000000000006 1.3380000000000001 0.68400000000000005`) and then convert to numbers with`as.numeric()`, but again the numbers have been truncated: `0,684 1,34 74,3`.

Please, let me know if you know the reason :)

Comment: When you say "in the R dataframe", how are you looking at your data?  I ask because it seems like R is reading your data correctly, but you are having a hard time seeing that it is read in correctly.  Notice the difference between `print(pi)` and `print(pi, digits=15)`.  In both cases, `pi` is just `pi`, but how much detail you get to see is different.

Comment: I tried. Doesn't matter if I `print(df[1,1], digits=5)` or `print(df[1,1], digits=1)`
it is always `74,3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful to not confuse "how many digits are there" vs. "how many digits R is showing you". It's hard to know for sure without seeing your code, but I suspect you are printing a tibble, something like this:

```
library(readxl)
my_junk <- read_excel("~/Downloads/test.xlsx")
print(my_junk)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>    test
#>   <dbl>
#> 1 0.684
#> 2 1.000
#> 3 1.00
```

The default print method for tibbles shows only a few significant digits. And it doesn't seem to respond to the digits setting in `options`. However if we convert it to a data.frame you will see that the digits were there all along:

```
library(dplyr)
my_junk %>%
  data.frame %>%
  print( digits = 7)  
#>       test
#> 1 0.684000
#> 2 0.999950
#> 3 1.000001
```

So your digits are likely there, they just aren't displaying.

Comment: Converting to data.frame helps.
I have managed to display the numbers properly in a tibble as well. Instead of setting 'digits' option, I set `options(pillar.sigfig = 5)` and now tibbles show 5 significant digits (3 by default).
Thanks for help :)